# Transparent image in QT

Tags: qt, image, qt4, transparency, symbian

i am new to QT, i got to know how to load a simple image on a window.
i want to know how to make transparent?.

please tell me the way to achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: i found answer here
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001515_-_Transparent_QPixmap_picture

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it:

```
canvas = new QImage(":/Zuerich.jpg");
city = new QImage(canvas->size(),QImage::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter p(city);
p.setOpacity(0.1);
p.drawImage(0,0,*canvas);
p.end();
// the proof:
QRgb pix = city->pixel(10,10);
qDebug() << "Alpha" << qAlpha(pix);
```